# why is [ ]==0 in java script?

Tags: javascript

```
Code:   
a=[1,2];   
b=[];

if(b==0){    
    console.log('0')    
}  
if(a==2){   
    console.log('2')  
}  
if([]==0){  
console.log('3')  
}  

Output:  
0  
3
```

in case if  [ ] is considered as an array of length 0 and == is comparing [ ] to its length.Why is [1,2]==2 false?

Comment: `[] == 0 == false == ''` - read about loose comparison. also read about `===`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not comparing against the length of the array, it's calling the `valueOf` function of the object, which (I think) is the same as `arr.join('')`.

```js
console.log(String([].valueOf()) === '');
console.log(String([1, 2].valueOf()) === '1,2');
```

The first one results in `''`, which is loosely equal to `0`.

The second one results in `'1,2'`.

Answer (score 0):

the `==` will do some conversation before do the comparison

```js
   
console.log([] == false) // true
console.log(0  == false) // true 
console.log([] == 0)     // true
```

also I suggest you read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)